# Passing objects to navigation / .map objects single page component

Tags: reactjs

I am learning  React and I have a problem that I don't know how to solve, so If you can please help me with it.
I want to create a simple react app, where I create 3 components with `.map()` method. I would like to pass the data to `Head` component that I can access to every single card separately.
I have used `.map()` method but all cards are on one page. Can I do that with `.map()` method, and pass data to `nav` component?

```
function Card(props) {



return (
  <Router>
```

```
<div id="wrapper">

   <Link to="#"><button id="request" href="#">
        REQUEST
      </button></Link>

<h1 id="naslov">{props.name}</h1>
<p>{props.key}</p>

  <div id="povez">
      <a id="srcek"><FiHeart /></a>
      <button id="follow">Follow</button>
      <a id="kocka"><FiExternalLink /></a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h4 className="he4der">ORIGIN</h4>
    <button id="origin">COUNTRY</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h4 className="he4der">GENRE</h4>
    <button id="origin">ROCK</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h4 className="he4der">SUBGENRES</h4>
    <button id="origin">ROCK</button>
    <button id="origin2">METAL</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button id="origin">ROCK</button>
    <a id="kocka2"><FiExternalLink /></a>
  </div>

  <div id="breaker"></div>

  <div id="socialinks">

  <div id="social">
    <span id="sicon"><FaFacebookF /></span>
    <span id="sicon"><FaTwitter /></span>
    <span id="sicon"><FaInstagram /></span>
    <span id="sicon"><FaSpotify /></span>

    </div>

     <div id="plus">
        <a id="kocka2"><FiExternalLink /></a>
   </div>

  </div>

 
  
</div>
```

```
)
```

}

export default Card

Comment: By navigation bar is it safe to assume you mean your `Head` component? What are you trying to pass to that component? You should really probably be using `Link` components over anchor tags, and you only need a single `Router` component to wrap your app and provide a routing context.

Comment: Yes, navigation is  Head component. I would like to pass artist_name to nav component, so that when i click on that name i can access card component that is related to that name/ artist

Comment: If I understand that comment you want to be able to pass an `artistName` prop from `App` to `Head` so `Head` can do something with the card components? Based on the code you've already it seems you are likely trying to pass an array of artists and render a list of links to them. Can you confirm what the desired behavior is that you are going for? A list of steps how interacting with your UI and what it should do is sufficient.

Comment: I am trying to pass artistName in Head component. So my goal is to create links, and when user clicks on link, card with artist is rendered

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to pass artist_name to nav component, so that when I
> click on that name I can access card component that is related to that
> name/artist.

Instead of passing a single artist it may make more sense to use `all_artists` and map your links. If `all_artists` isn't available globally it can be passed as a prop.

```
const Head = (props) => {
  return (
    <div id="header">
      <img src={Logo} id="logo" />
      <ul>
        {props.artists.map(({ artist_id, artist_name }) => (
          <li key={artist_id}>
            <Link to={`/artist/${artist_name}`}>{artist_name}</Link>
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>

      <div id="icns">
        <i><FiSearch /></i>
        <i><FiAlignJustify /></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Pass `all_artists` to `Head` and render a dynamic route to extract `name` from the path to be passed on to `Card` on the `name` prop. Notice the `Router` was moved here to provide a routing context for both the `Link` components in `Head` *and* the `Route` component in `App`.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Head artists={all_artists} />
        <Route
          path="/artist/:name"
          render={({ match: { params: { name } } }) => (
            <Card name={name}>
          )}
        />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Card` will need to utilize a lifecycle to "react" to any changes on the `name` prop, like fetching/loading specific artist data from an API endpoint or redux state.

Comment: Amazing, thank you for your help. Can you give me a reference how you would utilize a lifecycle for card component ?

Comment: Drew I really appreciate your help. Car is a functional component, can you help me with useEffect function ?

Comment: @eldzapo Sure. Can you update your question with the `Card` component then?

Comment: Thanks ! I have updated the post with card component

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass to your component(that is rendering the card) what is the artist_id( as props) that you want to display and then you could use find() array method to search/filter the object that you need inside the array since you already have the ID of the artist.

and you might want to use switch and map() method on your router if you want all artist to be in your navigation

something like this:

```
<Switch>
  { all_artists.map( artist => 
    <Route path=`/{artist.id}` render={ <CardComponent clickedArtist={artist} /> }/>
)}
</Switch>
```

Comment: Hey! Tnx 4 help. I have passed the id to the card component, but can you help me with creating navigation please? I can't find propper way to write functional code.